# Using datum w. numerical index instead of column name

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

Is there any way to access a column in datum using its positional index such as datum[1] (doesn't work) instead of datum.ColumnName or datum['ColumnName']?

Comment: No. What are you trying to do as there may be an alternative. All the columns provided by PBI to Deneb are named anyway.

Comment: It could be a simpler workaround to the issue where a Field Parameter sends into Deneb different columns depending on the selection in its slicer. 
With datum[1] it would be just one-line transform in Vega Lite. 

The workaround that I use now calls isDefined(datum['ColumnName']) for checking whether a ColumnName exists for every column included into a Field Parameter and uses if/then/else for creating a resulting column with predefined name.

Comment: I see. I suspect PBI doesn't guarantee column order to custom visuals anyway.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, they are coming into Deneb in the same order as listed in the Values box. Calculated columns (results of the transforms or in-encoding aggregation) are added to the right.  Did you see them out of that order?

Comment: No but there is probably no guarantee in the API that Deneb is using.